# Jasmine return TypeError: module is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a problem with Karma and Jasmine test for AngularJS controller. I read a lot about this subject on StackOverflow and I'm really sure that load files order is OK, but all time I get the error:

> ```
>     TypeError: module is not a function
>         at Suite.<anonymous> (/app/karma/developers/developer.ut.js:6:16)
>         at /app/karma/developers/developer.ut.js:1:1
> ```

My karma.config.js:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: './app',

    files: [
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'app.js',
      'developers/*.js',
      'karma/developers/*.js',
      'karma/*.js'
    ],

    autoWatch: true,

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    browsers: ['Chrome'],

    plugins: [
      'karma-chrome-launcher',
      'karma-firefox-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-junit-reporter'
    ],

    junitReporter: {
      outputFile: 'test_out/unit.xml',
      suite: 'unit'
    }

  });
};
```

And my developer.ut.js:

```
describe('DeveloperCtrl', function () {
    var $rootScope;
    var $controller;
    var YourControllerHere;

    beforeEach(module('myApp.developers'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {

        $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
        $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    }));
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
        YourControllerHere = $controller("DeveloperCtrl");
    }));

    it('jak działa', function () {
        expect(YourControllerHere.message).toBe("Hello");
    });
});
```

Comment: Is it possible any of `app.js` or `developers/*.js` has re-defined `window.module`? Do a file search for `"module ="`

Comment: I bet if you change it to `beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp.developers'))`, it would work :)

Comment: @Phil - thanks for your reply. I had "module = module('myApp.developers')" in my  controller. I change it but it doesn't help.
I change also module into angular.mock.module (your second tips) and it's work. Thank you. 

Can you explain why this is work? I really doesn't get it.

Comment: The Angular "mock" module registers it's own `angular.mock.module` function on `window` (ie, globally available as `module`). If you overwrite that variable on `window`, you cannot use it in your test specs. You should avoid creating global variables by wrapping your code in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), eg `(function() { var module = angular.module('myApp.developers'); ... })()`

Comment: Thanks for your help. You solve my problems.